# How does determinant method of solving equations work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, determinant

Say you have two equations

$ax+by+c=0$

$dx+ey+f=0$

by determinant method

$\frac{x}{bf-ce}=\frac{-y}{af-cd}=\frac{1}{ae-db}$

Clearly, the solution is valid

How exactly was this derived?

Comment: It’s logical to start by rewriting the system in terms of matrices $$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ d & e \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -c \\ -f \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: It is customary to write your equations as $ax+by=e$ and $cx+dy=f$ so that the determinant follows as $ad-bc$ which is then the denominator of your $(x,y)$ solutions. This is how the determinant is often introduced in texrtbooks

Comment: See if the index in your linear algebra textbook mentions "Cramer's Rule".

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor and then inverting first matrix? Thanks! I got it. Cant mark comments as answer though

Comment: @GEdgar no mention of Cramer's rule, I'll check Wikipedia, thanks

Comment: @AnvitGarg I posted it as an answer

Comment: A linear algebra textbook with no mention of Cramer's Rule?  That is an inferior book, in my opinion.

Comment: @GEdgar this method was taught to us 2 years earlier when we didn't know what determinants were. It was directly given as a formula. Now that we did learn determinants and I saw the relatedness that peaked my curiosity. But I do agree, the textbook isn't very good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by rewriting the system in terms of matrices.

$$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ d & e \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -c \\ -f \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Then, as you said, invert the square matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Anvit, using my set up of equations, here is a way: 
Multiply $ax+by=e$ by $d$ to get $adx+bdy=ed$ and multiply $cx+dy=f$ by $b$ to get $bcx+bdy=bf$. Now eliminating $bdy$ from both equations through subtraction yields $(ad-bc)x=ed-bf$ from which $x$ follows by division $ad-bc$ which is called determinant. For $y$ you can do the same thing. Can you give this a try?

EDIT: Considering $ad-bc$ and $ed-bf$ as determinants of two matrices, it ultimately gives Cramer's Rule

Answer (score -1):

it is $$x=\frac{ce-bf}{bd-ae},y=\frac{cd-af}{ae-bd}$$
and $$bd-ae$$ is the determinant, see also the Cramers rule

Comment: I was asking for derivation not solution. Sorry if question wasn't clear

Comment: your solution is wrong, thats why i posted this, see also Cramer's rule

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule

Comment: Our solutions are exactly the same.